# shell script before splash screen in pi

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi, daemon, startup

I have a raspberry pi running the Jessie OS, and would like to run a bash script to execute before it does anything else, such as the splash screen.

The shell script is a simple `feh` command because I want the pi to operate as a slideshow of images in a picture frame and nothing else; hence needing the pi to start the shell script immediately.

It would also be great if  I could have the functionality to restart it if the shell script is exited for any reason.

I have tried cron jobs, `/etc/init.d`, and `/etc/rc0.d`, however, none of these have worked for me yet.

I have my main shell script in `/home/imgs/slideshow.sh` and then I run the following script to set things up to *hopefully* run as init.d:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install feh
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver
sudo apt-get upgrade

# Make slideshow startup file in init.d if it doesn't exit
# if it does, make a backup file and rewrite it
FILE=/etc/init.d/slideshow.sh
if [ -f "$FILE" ]
then
    sudo mv $FILE $FILE-backup-$(date +"%F-%T")
else
    echo "$FILE does not exist but will be created"
fi

# input this text into the file
/bin/cat <<EOM >"$FILE"
#!/bin/sh -e

DAEMON="slideshow" #Command to run
daemon_OPT=""  #arguments for your program
DAEMONUSER="user" #Program user
daemon_NAME="slideshow" #Program name (need to be identical to the executable).

PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin" #don't touch

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

d_start () {
        log_daemon_msg "Starting system $daemon_NAME Daemon"
    start-stop-daemon --background --name $daemon_NAME --start --quiet --chuid $DAEMONUSER --exec $DAEMON -- $daemon_OPT
        log_end_msg $?
}

d_stop () {
        log_daemon_msg "Stopping system $daemon_NAME Daemon"
        start-stop-daemon --name $daemon_NAME --stop --retry 5 --quiet --name $daemon_NAME
    log_end_msg $?
}

case "$1" in

        start|stop)
                d_${1}
                ;;

        restart|reload|force-reload)
                        d_stop
                        d_start
                ;;

        force-stop)
               d_stop
                killall -q $daemon_NAME || true #replace with an apropriate killing method
                sleep 2
                killall -q -9 $daemon_NAME || true #replace with an apropriate killing method
                ;;

        status)
                status_of_proc "$daemon_NAME" "$DAEMON" "system-wide $daemon_NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
                ;;
        *)
                echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$daemon_NAME {start|stop|force-stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status}"
                exit 1
                ;;
esac
exit 0
EOM


sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/slideshow.sh
sudo chmod 0755 /etc/init.d/slideshow.sh
sudo chmod +x /home/pi/imgs/slideshow.sh
sudo chmod 0755 /home/pi/imgs/slideshow.sh
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo update-rc.d slideshow.sh defaults
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The splash screen is the hardware's way of saying "I'm alive and starting up". At this point, the OS has not been loaded, and so there is nothing that knows how to run a shell script. But I'd recommend using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q, and ask the moderator to move your Q to http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com . The experts there may have some tricks that can help you get as close as possible to your goal. Good luck.

Comment: I noticed later that the first four steps in your script are `sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install feh;
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver;
sudo apt-get upgrade` . This is definitely a non-starter, as `apt-get` implies so much extra software AND a working network connection, both of which imply/require a working OS to service the requests/functions. You'll have to reset your expectations on this ;-( . Sorry, but good luck!

Comment: thanks, so basically I can't do it before getting into the os, but this should work as soon as it gets the OS up right?

Comment: I'd take down this Q, and post a simpler query to http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com with a title "How to run program with network access asap on reboot". OR you can experiment further with init.d and rc0.d to see where it is safe to insert your script. Good luck.